# Use Mono.Cecil to determine if a type implements an interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, mono.cecil

I had a look through the documentation on the Wiki, but it seems a bit thin.  How do I determine if a type implements a given interface using Cecil?  For my particular implementation it is important that I do not actually load the type into the AppDomain.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
Dim outputModule As ModuleDefinition = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(outputFile)

For Each assemblyType As TypeDefinition In outputModule.Types
    'How to determine if assemblyType implements a specific interface?
Next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# I have implemented it comparing the full name of the interfaces:

```
if (assemblyType.Interfaces.Any(
  type => type.Resolve().FullName == typeof(YourInterface).FullName
)) {
  // ...
}
```

You can also compare `TypeDefinition`s if you have the one for your interface.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what the Resolve method is doing or point me toward some documentation?  It's not loading the type into the AppDomain is it?

Comment: @Matt: `Resolve` gets the `TypeDefinition` from a `TypeReference`. Basically a type can be referenced in many places, and you use `Resolve` to get its definition from one of those references.

Comment: ... and no, it's not loading the type in the app domain.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: Wont type.FullName work in place of type.Resolve().FullName? it would be faster as well

Comment: @Simon: if `YourInterface` is not generic, you're right. But if it is (e.g `YourInterface<T>`), then it can fail without the `Resolve()` call. You could end up comparing `YourInterface<int>` to `YourInterface<>`, for example.

Comment: fair enough. in my use case generics dont come into it. thanks